# For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having this weird error right there

```
val limit: Int = applicationContext.resources.getInteger(R.integer.popupPlayerAnimationTime)
for(i in limit) {

}
```

I've found similar answer about that error but no one worked for me

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you use:

```
for(item in items)
```

`items` needs an `iterator` method; you're iterating over the object itself.

If you want to iterate an int in a range, you have two options:

```
for(i in 0..limit) {
    // x..y is the range [x, y]
}
```

Or

```
for(i in 0 until limit) {
    // x until y is the range [x, y>
}
```

Both of these creates an `IntRange`, which extends `IntProgression`, which implements `Iterable`. If you use other data types (i.e. float, long, double), it's the same.

---

For reference, this is perfectly valid code:

```
val x: List<Any> = TODO("Get a list here")
for(item in x){}
```

because `List` is an Iterable. `Int` is not, which is why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Just to add a 3rd option: ```for(i in 10 downto 0) { }```