# Iterate over children in Cloud Firestore (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to migrate from Real-time database to Cloud firestore in firebase. I am having some problems with re-writing code, that iterates over children in the db.

My old code looks like this:

```
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (x in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    FetchInformation(x.key)
                }
            }
```

And for Firestore it looks like this:

```
            if (snapshot!!.exists()) {

            for (x in snapshot){
                FetchInformation(x.key)
            }


        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null")
        }
```

However, nothing like snapshot.children exists for firestore and I am receving compile error

> 'For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method

Comment: Please add your Firebase realtime database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also add your Firestore database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
for(i in 0..snapshot) {
    // x..y is the range [x, y]
}
```

or

```
for(i in 0 until snapshot) {
    // x until y is the range [x, y>
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52356604/for-loop-range-must-have-an-iterator-method/52357184#52357184)